# Is it OK to not include a header file which has a define of struct?

Tags: c

I have `a.h`:

```
#include "b.h"  // XX

struct A {
 int asdf;
 struct B *b;
};
extern struct A aaa;
```

Also `b.h`

```
#include "a.h"

struct B {
 int asdf;
 int ghjk;
}
static inline void sth() { aaa.asdf*** }
```

It gives following errors:

```
b.h:17:6: error: ‘aaa’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

But if I remove line `XX`, the compile succeeds.

Is it OK to do that?

Comment: A non-inline, non-static function body in a header is itself a code smell. Regardless, you don't need to include b.h in a.h, so if this is some attempt to solve a circular include dependency, just don't do it in the first place.

Comment: @WhozCraig sorry, it is a `static inline void`

Comment: 2 headers depending on each other is often sign of poor design, because it hints that your modules don't have clear responsibilites. Maybe you should consider breaking these into smaller modules, so that there are only one-way relationships.

Comment: Your examples lack header guards which are heavily recommended for 99% of the headers. You have to use them and forward declarations, if you don't refactor your code to smaller modules,

Comment: `extern` alone is code smell.

Answer (score 0):

The compile might work if you remove that line, but the program won't link.

- You have to *define* `aaa` somewhere.
- Your header files must be surrounded by `#ifndef HEADER_H`... header guards.
- Having two header files that include each other is a sign of bad program design.
- The presence of `extern` anywhere in your code is a sign of bad program design, with very few exceptions.
- There are a few cases where you can place a (static inline) function definition inside a header file, but most of the time that means bad program design.

Summary: really bad program design leads to really bad programs.